# Script para recuperar cliente

Tags: javascript, html

Como se chama aquele código que quando o cliente vai sair da página aparece uma popup com alguma oferta ou pedindo para o cliente não sair?

Alguém pode dar exemplo de algum código?

Comment: Não sei se tem nome, mas eu chamaria ele de "xaropão" ou coisa do tipo. Na verdade isso não é nada especial, é simplesmente um "if" que detecta quando o mouse saiu da janela pela parte de cima. É um bom meio de tentar prender o cliente pela insistência, já que o conteúdo não é bom suficiente pra isso.

Comment: Isso mesmo, sabe como se chama? tem algum código de exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Se chama "Confirmação", os navegadores implementam o método global `confirm(mensagem)`.

Esse método para a execução da página, ou seja, é síncrono, depois que você receber a resposta do cliente que a página irá continuar executando, ele retorna `true` ou `false` (e talvez `null`).

O evento "beforeunload" permite que o método `confirm` faça aparecer esse tipo de confirmação antes de sair da página se for definido com o puro `confirm`, sem usar os métodos de adicionar evento do DOM:

```
self.onbeforeunload = confirm;
```

[image: e.g.]

Ou seja, não é possível escolher sua própria mensagem ao sair da página! Nem com `Function#bind` (porque cria uma nova função com a mesma).

Answer (score -3):

Acho que você esta se referindo ao `alert("mensagem")` do Javascript. Se for esse, você pode encontrar exemplos e utilizações [aqui.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/84377)

Comment: Entendido, obrigado.